# why I can't move a windows form in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

this is probably an easy question but why I can't move a windows form while editing?
I mean, the tools box dont let me see the windows form and I cant move it to the other side, here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo3km.png)

Comment: Click the "pin" in the toolbox title bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top left of the windows form will always stay at 0,0 in designer mode. To see it clearly in this case, just pin the tool box open, by clicking on the pin icon.